# How to scroll programatically a ScrollView?

Tags: android

I have a little problem with a ScrollView. I have a layout for an activity which is made with a ScrollView. This scrollview contains two ListViews.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rootViewGroup" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scrollbars="vertical">

<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="top" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/cmb_bg">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/accountsListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scrollbars="none" />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/cardsListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scrollbars="none" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In the `onCreate` method of my activity I compute ListViews height according their contents.

During execution, on activity launch, ScrollView is already scrolled a bit.

So I tried, at the end of onCreate to call method `scrollTo(0, 0)`, but it does not change anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AHHH!!! Remove ScrollView and leave only ONE ListView in your activity. It's not intended to work this way
.If you want to have different content in your ONE listView - modify your adapter, or change the UI 
But never, ever put different scrollable containers on the same screen/inside each other
here is a related post.
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/e7c8df374fe31733#
In theory you can slap two listview on the screen, but expect things to be weird. And i would really redesign it with with either separators or expanders or just with one ListView.

Comment: There is a very nice example which you can bend and make really flex
by Jeff Sharkey
http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/